# ActiveRecord ignores before_create hook from concern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have model of subscription to news topic, witch has secret field for subscription/unsubscription:

```
class TopicSubscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  include WithSecret
  ...
end
```

here is code of module, which generates subscription secret

```
module WithSecret
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    attr_accessible :secret
    validates_presence_of :secret    
    before_create :gen_secret
  end

  def gen_secret
    begin
      o =  [('a'..'z'),('0'..'9')].map{|i| i.to_a}.flatten
      code  =  (0...128).map{ o[rand(o.length)] }.join
    end while self.class.send(:"find_by",{secret: code})
    self.send("secret=",code)
  end
end
```

problem if that gen_secret hook never fires and I always get validation error. What is purpose of such strange behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`before_create` fires after validation. Use `before_validation :gen_secret, on: :create` instead.

Comment: I used `after_initialize` callback, but It seems that not elegant solution for my task. Your solution is better, thanks a lot!